# Can I find an element nested inside a tag in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the website `https://www.medline.com/catalog/category-products.jsp?No=0&itemId=Z05-CA11_07_03&N=104048&iclp=Z05-CA11_07_03` that I wish to crawl.

I need to go to the link of each product, whose xpath is given by:

```
//div[@class='medGridProdTitle']//a
```

I wrote the following piece of code to get all these links. But it returns `none` for them all. I know I haven't included `a` in the tag, and that is creating problems, but I don't know how I can do that.

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
def cpap_spider(max_pages):
    global row_i
    page=0
    while page<=max_pages:
        url= "https://www.medline.com/catalog/category-products.jsp?No="+str(page)+"&itemId=Z05-CA11_07_03&N=104048&iclp=Z05-CA11_07_03"
        source_code= requests.get(url)
        plain_text= source_code.text
        soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll("div", {"class":"medGridProdTitle"}):
            href=link.get("href")
            title = link.string
            
            print(href)
            #print(title)
        page+=12
cpap_spider(156)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So you just need to change the way you find the href a little bit. Here is an example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
def cpap_spider(max_pages):
    global row_i
    page=0
    while page<=max_pages:
        url= "https://www.medline.com/catalog/category-products.jsp?No="+str(page)+"&itemId=Z05-CA11_07_03&N=104048&iclp=Z05-CA11_07_03"
        source_code= requests.get(url)
        plain_text= source_code.text
        soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        links = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"medGridProdTitle"})
        for link in links:
            print(link.find('a')['href']) # this is the line you have to change.
        page+=12
cpap_spider(156)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
def cpap_spider(max_pages):
    global row_i
    page=0
    while page<=max_pages:
        url= "https://www.medline.com/catalog/category-products.jsp?No="+str(page)+"&itemId=Z05-CA11_07_03&N=104048&iclp=Z05-CA11_07_03"
        source_code= requests.get(url)
        plain_text= source_code.text
        soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')
        for link in soup.findAll("div", {"class":"medGridProdTitle"}):
            href = link.find("a")['href']
                       
            print(href)
            
        page+=12
```